# Custom TextInputLayout gets wrong values set on back pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, material-components-android, android-viewbinding

In my app I'm using custom view containing a `TextInputLayout` with the following code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout"
        style="@style/UbiInput2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="-"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/input_value"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

And the kotlin

```
      class TextInputView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : LinearLayout(context, attrs) {
        
            var errorMessage: String? = ""
        
            init {
                inflate(context, R.layout.text_input_view, this)
                val attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextInputView)
                val inputLayout = findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.input_layout)
                val inputValue = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.input_value)
                inputLayout.hint = attributes.getString(R.styleable.TextInputView_hint)
                inputValue.hint = attributes.getString(R.styleable.TextInputView_placeholderText)
                inputLayout.isExpandedHintEnabled =
                    attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.TextInputView_expandedHintEnabled, true)
                errorMessage = attributes.getString(R.styleable.TextInputView_errorMessage)
                inputLayout.isHelperTextEnabled = false
                inputValue.inputType =
                    attributes.getInt(
                        R.styleable.TextInputView_android_inputType,
                        InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                    )
                if (attributes.hasValue(R.styleable.TextInputView_android_maxLength)) {
                    inputValue.filters += InputFilter.LengthFilter(
                        attributes.getInt(
                            R.styleable.TextInputView_android_maxLength,
                            100
                        )
                    )
                }
                inputValue.gravity =
                    attributes.getInt(R.styleable.TextInputView_android_gravity, Gravity.START)
                if (attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.TextInputView_android_gravity, false)) {
                    inputLayout.helperText = attributes.getString(R.styleable.TextInputView_helperText)
                }
                if (attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.TextInputView_helperTextEnabled, false)) {
                    inputLayout.isHelperTextEnabled = true
                    inputLayout.helperText = attributes.getString(R.styleable.TextInputView_helperText)
                }
        
                inputLayout.startIconDrawable =
                    attributes.getDrawable(R.styleable.TextInputView_startIconDrawable)
                 attributes.recycle()
            }
    }

@BindingAdapter("textValue")
fun TextInputView.setTextValue(value: String?) {
    value?.let {
        setValue(value)
    }
}

@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "textValue")
fun TextInputView.getTextValue(): String {
    return value()
}

@BindingAdapter("textValueAttrChanged")
fun TextInputView.setListener(textAttrChanged: InverseBindingListener) {
    val inputValue = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.input_value)

    inputValue.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            textAttrChanged.onChange()
        }
    })
}
```

I have the following screen which go to the next fragment on button click. Using Navigation component.

[image]

But from the next screen, when I'm pressing back button to come back to the search form, the `TextInputLayout` values for `hint`, and `helperText` are all the same.
The only place I set those is inside the custom view. And from debugging I can see that all the correct values are set at that time.

[image]

I'm a bit out of ideas about what's going on there. Any hints would be appreciated.

Material library version used: `1.3.0-alpha04`

All codebase has been migrated to view binding [according the latest changes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration)

The View is used as followed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.ubigo.features.v2.products.taxi.SearchViewModel" />

        <variable
            name="dateFormat"
            type="com.ubigo.ubicore.date.UbiDate" />
    </data>
    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/rental_search_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background">
        
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/rental_search_form"
            style="@style/WhiteCardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.ubigo.ubicore.ui.TextInputView
                    android:id="@+id/pickup"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    app:hint="@string/product_start"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_calendar"
                    app:textValue="@{dateFormat.getPrettyDate(viewModel.pickupDateTime)}" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/divider6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pickup" />

                <com.ubigo.ubicore.ui.TextInputView
                    android:id="@+id/dropoff"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    app:hint="@string/product_end"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider6"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_calendar"
                    app:textValue="@{dateFormat.getPrettyDate(viewModel.destinationDatetime)}" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <com.ubigo.ubicore.ui.LoaderButton
            android:id="@+id/rental_search_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="@string/product_rental_show_car"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rental_search_location" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/rental_search_location"
            style="@style/WhiteCardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rental_search_form">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.ubigo.ubicore.ui.TextInputView
                    android:id="@+id/user_location"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    app:helperText="@string/product_rental_location"
                    app:helperTextEnabled="true"
                    app:hint="@string/product_pickup_location"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_location_on_black_24dp"
                    app:textValue="@{viewModel.depAddress}" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:text="@string/product_rental_weekend"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

And the initialization of the Fragment:

```
class RentalSearchFragment : Fragment() {

    val viewModel: SearchViewModel by viewModel()

    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private var _binding: FragmentRentalSearchBinding? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        if (_binding == null) {
            _binding = FragmentRentalSearchBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
            binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
            binding.viewModel = viewModel
            binding.dateFormat = UbiDate()
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Comment: Same problem, did you find solution?

Comment: similar issue when adding TextInputLayout dynamically inside  for loop . 
solved by calling infalte and addView inside post method.

View.post {
//inflate
//add view
}

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this exact problem by implementing onSaveInstanceState, onRestoreInstanceState, dispatchSaveInstanceState, dispatchRestoreInstanceState, and setValues as described here

http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/03/custom-compound-view-in-android.html

The linked above goes into all the necessary detail about how to implement these functions.  There's also undoubtedly countless other sources you can find about how to implement this android paradigm.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just FYI that comment was dropped by someone who saw your answer. It's just that the software doesn't show the person who shared the feedback. Don't worry, it's not a bot automatically dropping comments!

Comment: While the argument in your edit may be valid, it's meta-commentary, i.e. it's not about the technical content of the question or the answer, and as such, is not appropriate in the answer box. Please don't add such text to the answer. Also, the comment you're responding to is simply suggesting that you expand upon your answer; it's entirely up to you whether you want to do that, or not.